# Displaying the categories and subcategories - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, html-lists

i have a lot of categories and subcategories in my site. I display them manually, i mean i wrote:

```
<ul>
<li>..menu..</li>
<li>..menu..</li>
</ul>
```

I'm sure there is a right way to do it. I'm sure there is an function for that. Can anybody tell me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can use wp_list_categories()

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

Use [**`wp_list_categories()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories):

**An example:**

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=name&show_count=1&exclude=10'); ?> 
</ul>
```

This function takes care of the formatting too. If you want the unformatted results, you can use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) instead..

Answer (score 0):

In most php-based content management systems, this will be handled by getting the object containing the categories and a foreach() loop.

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($menus as $menu) {
    echo "<li>" . $menu->link . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Every CMS will have its own objects, but the loop is pretty standard.